# How to restart SystemD service (screen) after Out-Of-Memory crash

Tags: java, systemd, service

I am using SystemD service to control Java-based server (OK! Its Minecraft :D) trough screen like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=mc@auth
After=local-fs.target network.target mysqld.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft/auth
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft
Type=forking

Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

ExecStart=/bin/bash ./server.sh start

ExecStop=/bin/bash ./server.sh stop
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "while ps -p $MAINPID > /dev/null; do /bin/sleep 1; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`server.sh start` just starts jar file by `java -jar Example.jar` and outputs console.

How to restart this service when I get Out Of Memory error? Java seems to not exit back into shell when OOM occurs.

Comment: Why do you call a shell script instead of the actual program? This always causes problems. You should call the program directly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `java -jar Example.jar -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemory` in the `server.sh` and set `Restart=on-failure` in the Systemd unit file.

Comment: It is "Unrecognized VM option" on Java 11 (OpenJDK)

Comment: I think for Java 11 you have to use `java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -11 %p" JavaProgram` https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jrockit-hotspot/migration-guide/cloptions.htm#JRHMG129

Comment: What about `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` that works (it starts) but I not tested functionality

Comment: Don't know. You need to make sure that the Java process terminates when Java hits OOM.